# How to add config transform for custom config file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, web-config

Visual Studio natively supports adding custom config transforms for web.config. Is there a way to do the same thing for a custom config file? For instance, the shop I'm at has an `EnvironmentConfigs` directory in the root of the project and there are custom `appSettings.config` and `connectionStrings.config` files. Is there a way to do the same thing that web.config does and add `appSettings.Release.config` and `connectionStrings.Release.config` transformation files that will transform them on publish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about config's like that, but check out the Slow Cheetah extension in VS2010.  You can install it by going to the Tools > Extension Manager and search the Online Gallery.  It adds the ability to use config transforms for App.Config's and possibly will work in the scenario you describe.  It adds a lot of transform functionality in general (even to web.config's) so it's a great tool to use.  Out of the box, VS2010 will not do that, though.

Edit: According to the description for SlowCheetah: "This package enables you to transform app.config or any other XML file based on the build configuration".  So yes, it seems it will do what you need...

Comment: Unfortunately this transformation isn't happening in VS. It's happening on a remote service by a publishing application known as "kudu". I'm thinking a VS extension won't be applying it's magic over there. Kudu allows us to push to a remote git repo and then kudu automatically builds and publishes the project on that system. It transforms web.config fine, but not the custom ones.

Comment: Interesting.  I'm not familiar with Kudu.  So Kudu is what's doing the transformation's?  Is it using msbuild (or something from .NET/VS) to handle the transformations or is it doing it internally?  AFAIK, Microsoft VS doesn't support any transformations besides Web.config.  I did quite a bit of research on this before finding SlowCheetah.

Comment: Although probably not suited to the poster, +1 for SlowCheetah. We use it in our build process. It's a great product.

Comment: @AdamPlocher It is using MSBUILD.

Comment: I ended up just moving the external configs back into web.config. Seemed the easiest solution. I will be looking at slowcheetah for sure though.